# Android app can't run on real device, but does recognize it

Tags: android

I'm trying to write my first android app.
Eclipse does recognise my phone, but can't launch the app on it. The "OK" button can't be pressed.

Any idea?
Thanks

[image]

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.app1"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Solved.

The problem is with my phone.
I checked with another device and it was OK.

Thanks and sorry for botherring.

Comment: Check you minSdkVersion and your current Android version on you device.

Comment: well does it recogised you device with green color right mark, or with some red or other color mark, other than the right mark?

Comment: could you show us your manifest file to validate what @PozzoApps is pointing out.

Comment: By your picture I cant be sure, but maybe try to restart or another driver =/

Comment: Reinstall USB driver.

Comment: PDWagela - I can't understand which marks you mean.

Comment: @PozzoApps - my minSdkVersion is 8 and targetSdkVersion is 18. It didn't work as weel with 19,20,21.
I'm using Galaxy S3.

Comment: Well, but by your picture the version is not the problem, and the marks commented are a level after, the device must be fully connected, only then it will show a green or a red mark, but yours is getting some problem on connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your `SDK` is up to date using `Android SDK Manager` in Eclipse. If not update it. Install `min sdk version` and `max sdk version` package you want.
2. Check if `OEM drivers` for the respective device are installed on the PC and Developer options on the phone are activated. To know what are OEM drivers check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)
3. Lastly check for hardware loose connection in the USB wire and unplug and plug it again. :) :P